# how to realize threads dump in python (like threads dump in java)

Tags: django, multithreading

I have a django project, and nowadays I have met a performance problem. I want to analyze the main problem using threads dump. But I have searched a lot of pages, found nothing valuable. Is there a way to dump threads stack in python, or is there some useful modules in django to analyze bottleneck.

Comment: It may be worth starting by analyzing the application's SQL using the django-debug-toolbar, or by turning on SQL query logging. Poorly performing SQL queries are very often the cause of application performance problems.

Comment: thanks, but i want to get a overall profile first. using java i can find whether lots of jdbc handlings exist in threads dump, so i wonder if there is something likewise in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer No.

But there is a solution to iterates over all threads and output the stack.

Something like this http://bzimmer.ziclix.com/2008/12/17/python-thread-dumps/

Hope it helps!

Comment: seems it works, i will try to integrate it to my django project.